# ASP.NET Dropdown Menu not refreshing data

Tags: dynamic, refresh, xmldatasource, aspmenu

I am constructing an ASP.NET Menu using an asp:XmlDataSource and setting the Data property and binding the Menu.  Everything works well until I have to change the menu. For instance when I remove a menu item from the xml and set the Data to a new xml string and rebind the menu.  The item is missing from the datasource but still shows up in the menu.  I double check to make sure it is not a refresh problem by doing a Menu.FindItem with the path to the item , which still shows up in the menu.  I have even opened the page in another bowser and the item still shows up, so it must be a server issue.

Is there some chaching on the server that needs to be reset or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I will solve my own issue.

The thread at: http://forums.asp.net/t/1239541.aspx/1/10 showed that the xmldatasource has the EnableCaching set to true by default, so even though I was changing the Data property the changes were never making it to the menu.